# OpenVidu Android app crashes when leaving the session?

Tags: java, android, webrtc, voip, openvidu

I am trying to fix this issue that persists in the OpenVidu android doc. When I try to leave the session the app crashes with the below stacktrace.

------------- Stacktrace ----------------

```
2020-05-13 18:37:11.268 16277-18122/in.app.chirpz I/org.webrtc.Logging: WebRtcAudioTrackExternal: Stopping the AudioTrackThread…
2020-05-13 18:37:11.287 16277-18108/in.app.chirpz E/org.webrtc.Logging: EglRenderer: Exception on EglRenderer thread
2020-05-13 18:37:11.288 16277-18108/in.app.chirpz E/org.webrtc.Logging: EglRenderer: java.lang.RuntimeException: glUseProgram: GLES20 error: 1282
2020-05-13 18:37:11.288 16277-18108/in.app.chirpz E/org.webrtc.Logging: EglRenderer: java.lang.RuntimeException: glUseProgram: GLES20 error: 1282
at org.webrtc.GlUtil.checkNoGLES2Error(GlUtil.java:37)
at org.webrtc.GlShader.useProgram(GlShader.java:118)
at org.webrtc.GlGenericDrawer.prepareShader(GlGenericDrawer.java:246)
at org.webrtc.GlGenericDrawer.drawOes(GlGenericDrawer.java:159)
at org.webrtc.GlRectDrawer.drawOes(GlRectDrawer.java:14)
at org.webrtc.VideoFrameDrawer.drawTexture(VideoFrameDrawer.java:40)
at org.webrtc.VideoFrameDrawer.drawFrame(VideoFrameDrawer.java:213)
at org.webrtc.EglRenderer.renderFrameOnRenderThread(EglRenderer.java:662)
at org.webrtc.EglRenderer.lambda$vWDJEj1GWjHSjwoQQjEEK_IVOJE(Unknown Source:0)
at org.webrtc.-$$Lambda$EglRenderer$vWDJEj1GWjHSjwoQQjEEK_IVOJE.run(Unknown Source:2)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at org.webrtc.EglRenderer$HandlerWithExceptionCallback.dispatchMessage(EglRenderer.java:103)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:201)
at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:65)
2020-05-13 18:37:11.290 16277-18108/in.app.chirpz E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: local_gl_surface_viewEglRenderer
Process: in.app.chirpz, PID: 16277
java.lang.RuntimeException: glUseProgram: GLES20 error: 1282
at org.webrtc.GlUtil.checkNoGLES2Error(GlUtil.java:37)
at org.webrtc.GlShader.useProgram(GlShader.java:118)
at org.webrtc.GlGenericDrawer.prepareShader(GlGenericDrawer.java:246)
at org.webrtc.GlGenericDrawer.drawOes(GlGenericDrawer.java:159)
at org.webrtc.GlRectDrawer.drawOes(GlRectDrawer.java:14)
at org.webrtc.VideoFrameDrawer.drawTexture(VideoFrameDrawer.java:40)
at org.webrtc.VideoFrameDrawer.drawFrame(VideoFrameDrawer.java:213)
at org.webrtc.EglRenderer.renderFrameOnRenderThread(EglRenderer.java:662)
at org.webrtc.EglRenderer.lambda$vWDJEj1GWjHSjwoQQjEEK_IVOJE(Unknown Source:0)
at org.webrtc.-$$Lambda$EglRenderer$vWDJEj1GWjHSjwoQQjEEK_IVOJE.run(Unknown Source:2)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at org.webrtc.EglRenderer$HandlerWithExceptionCallback.dispatchMessage(EglRenderer.java:103)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:201)
at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:65)
```

I am following this tutorial here --> https://docs.openvidu.io/en/2.14.0/tutorials/openvidu-android/

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: any luck! i am also stuck in same place

Comment: No progress yet, wil update if I find a solution.

Comment: @Mohd Qasim, try this link.[Crash Fix](https://openvidu.discourse.group/t/openvidu-android-project-crashes-when-leaving-the-session/784/16?u=sidharth)

Answer (score 0):

glUseProgram: GLES20 error: 1282 means Graphic OME.
I suggest, release and clearImage to other SurfaceViewRenderers.
So other streams will be stopped and memory will not be filled